# JQuery sortable does not drop on overflow list items

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists - the first contains a list of items the user can select, and he selects them by dragging them to the second list.  I have implemented this with jQuery UI Sortable, and created a basic example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/halm/Fr7hN/1/).

So drag an item from the first to the second list - OK.  The problem occurs if you scroll down to the bottom of the second list - you are unable to drag an item from the first to the second list.  It appears that all list items that overflowed beyond the end of the visible list do not have a drop target associated with them.  Same happens when copying in the other direction.

As sortable appears to be aimed at lists, I suspect I am missing a trick.  Any ideas?

The jsfiddle example code is:

**html**

```
<div class="listDiv">
    <ul id="list1" class="connected ui-sortable">
        <li id="a">a</li>
        <li id="b">b</li>
        <li id="c">c</li>
        <li id="d">d</li>
        <li id="e">e</li>
        <li id="f">f</li>
        <li id="g">g</li>
        <li id="h">h</li>
        <li id="i">i</li>
        <li id="j">j</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="listDiv">
    <ul id="list1" class="connected ui-sortable">
        <li id="1">1</li>
        <li id="2">2</li>
        <li id="3">3</li>
        <li id="4">4</li>
        <li id="5">5</li>
        <li id="6">6</li>
        <li id="7">7</li>
        <li id="8">8</li>
        <li id="9">9</li>
        <li id="10">10</li>
        <li id="11">11</li>
        <li id="12">12</li>
        <li id="13">13</li>
        <li id="14">14</li>
        <li id="15">15</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(function() {
   $( "#list1, #list2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connected"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

**css**

```
.listDiv {
    overflow:auto; 
    float: left; 
    width:400px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

#list1, #list2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 200px;
}

#list1 li, #list2 li {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #C5DBEC;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: medium none;
}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have nailed down the version of jquery ui sortable in which the bug was introduced - 1.8.12.  The following code appears to cause the error:

`//We ignore calculating positions of all connected containers when we're not over them
if(item.instance != this.currentContainer && this.currentContainer && item.item[0] != this.currentItem[0])
    continue;`

I have reported this on jquery ui bug [4231](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4231) in the hope that they will reopen this (unfixed) bug and fix it in a future release.

So if you are struggling with this problem you can check if the bug has been fixed, or revert back to jquery ui 1.8.11, or otherwise remove the offending code mentioned above and hope for the best!

Comment: Looks like the actual jquery ui bug dealing with this issue is http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7065, and that a fix is planned for version 2.0.0.